# how many instances are needed to do a text classification?

Tags: classification, sentiment-analysis

I am currently trying to gather data for doing a text classification that determines whether the content of the text is "depressing" or not. it is going to be a binary classification.

my question is :
how many instances(sentences) are needed to do an acceptable text classification ?

Comment: How do you define "acceptable"?

Comment: @csismylife You have to test your classification and then you are the one who decides whether the performance is "acceptable".

Comment: @jros I am doing a project which is actually my first project. obviously I am not trying to turn this into a product but I want to make a descent model that if s.b sees it he won't be like "your model is not good since your data is not enough".

Comment: @frank thanks frank but I was trying to see whether there is a "threshold" that my instances have to pass. but you are also right. if the model works good enough on my test set, maybe it is an indicator that my project's model is good enough